# How can I use og:title and og:description for Twitter cards in Docusaurus 2?

Tags: twitter, seo, docusaurus

I'm wondering how I can reuse the `title` and `description` metadata for Twitter cards title and description, respectively. Docusaurus uses these values to populate `og:title` and `og:description` already so perhaps there is a way to pass these values as argument for Twitter cards generation.

Answer (score 1):

If the `og:` tags are present, Twitter cards will use them. You will need a `twitter:card` tag to specify the card type, though - the rest can be `og:` tags equivalent to the Twitter Cards markup.